# SQL Server Detail Query with totals and grand totals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, group-by, calculated-columns

I am trying to generate a single SQL query result set that will allow me to reproduce a detail billing report that has totals by location, and a grand total for all locations at the end.  (we are porting from Crystal Reports)

Unfortunately, the details are in many tables joined together, and it is not as simple as the examples I have found.

Here's what I want for data output:

```
ID  LastName  FirstName  Location  TestDateTime  ReaderLastName    ReaderFirstName   FeeCharged
1   Test      Mary       MyTown    12/01/2014    Smith             Tom              10
2   Test      John       MyTown    12/02/2014    Smith             Tom              10
                         MyTown                                                     20
3   Testing   Andy       YourTown  12/12/2014    Cabin             Fred             15
4   Jones     Lou        YourTown  12/13/2014    Cabin             Fred             15
5   Sun       Mike       YourTown  12/15/2014    Boat              Karen            15
                         YourTown                                                   45
                         All                                                        65
```

Here is what I have done so far, which is to get the two separate parts I am looking for... first the detail portion, with a sum by location:

```
SELECT
    tpd.ID, 
    tpd.LastName,
    tpd.FirstName,
    cl.Location, 
    ttd.TestDateTime, 
    ttd.ReaderLastName, 
    ttd.ReaderFirstName,
    cld.FeeCharged 
FROM   ((tstTestDemographics ttd 
INNER JOIN cfgLocationsDispatches cld 
ON ttd.Location=cld.LocationID) 
INNER JOIN tstPatientDemographics tpd 
ON ttd.TestID=tpd.TestID) 
INNER JOIN cfgLocations cl
ON cld.LocationID=cl.LocationID
WHERE  ttd.TestStatus=1 AND tpd.TestID>0 
AND cld.FeeCharged<>0 
AND (ttd.TestDateTime>={ts '2014-11-01 00:00:00'} 
AND ttd.TestDateTime<{ts '2014-12-01 00:00:00'})
ORDER BY cl.Location, ttd.TestDateTime
COMPUTE SUM(cld.FeeCharged)  BY cl.Location
```

This, however, produces multiple sets, and I'd rather have one big set.

Here is the query I have for the subtotals only and the grand total, so far:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (Grouping(cl.Location) = 1) THEN 'Grand Total for Month'
    ELSE ISNULL(cl.Location, 'UNKNOWN')
    END as LocationName, 
    SUM(cld.FeeCharged) as 'FeeCharged Total'
FROM   ((tstTestDemographics ttd 
INNER JOIN cfgLocationsDispatches cld 
ON ttd.Location=cld.LocationID) 
INNER JOIN tstPatientDemographics tpd 
ON ttd.TestID=tpd.TestID) 
INNER JOIN cfgLocations cl
ON cld.LocationID=cl.LocationID
WHERE  ttd.TestStatus=1 AND tpd.TestID>0 
AND cld.FeeCharged<>0 
AND (ttd.TestDateTime>={ts '2014-11-01 00:00:00'} 
AND ttd.TestDateTime<{ts '2014-12-01 00:00:00'})
GROUP BY cl.Location WITH ROLLUP
```

Is there some way I can get the detail list and the subtotals and grand totals in one big query?

My attempts with grouping have given me lots of duplicates and null values that I don't really want.
I am new to the Rollup and Grouping functions.  I think my database is SQL Server 2005, since some of the advanced 2008 Grouping syntax isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `Fee Charged` to be added up.  Use `grouping sets`, basically on the first query:

```
SELECT tpd.ID, tpd.LastName, tpd.FirstName,
       (CASE WHEN (Grouping(cl.Location) = 1) THEN 'ALL' ELSE cl.Location END) as location,
       ttd.TestDateTime,
       ttd.ReaderLastName, ttd.ReaderFirstName,
       SUM(cld.FeeCharged) as FeeCharged
FROM tstTestDemographics ttd INNER JOIN
     cfgLocationsDispatches cld 
     ON ttd.Location=cld.LocationID INNER JOIN
     tstPatientDemographics tpd ON
     ttd.TestID = tpd.TestID INNER JOIN
     cfgLocations cl
     ON cld.LocationID = cl.LocationID
WHERE ttd.TestStatus = 1 AND tpd.TestID > 0 AND
      cld.FeeCharged <> 0 AND
      (ttd.TestDateTime>={ts '2014-11-01 00:00:00'} AND
       ttd.TestDateTime<{ts '2014-12-01 00:00:00'}) 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((tpd.ID, tpd.LastName, tpd.FirstName, cl.Location, ttd.TestDateTime, ttd.ReaderLastName, ttd.ReaderFirstName),
                       (cl.location)
                      ) 
ORDER BY cl.Location, ttd.TestDateTime
```

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2005, you can do this with a union.  I'd put most of the logic in a CTE, so repeated it is easy.  The query would look something like this:

```
WITH CTE as (
      SELECT tpd.ID, tpd.LastName, tpd.FirstName, cl.Location,
             ttd.TestDateTime, ttd.ReaderLastName, ttd.ReaderFirstName, cld.FeeCharged
      FROM tstTestDemographics ttd INNER JOIN
           cfgLocationsDispatches cld 
           ON ttd.Location=cld.LocationID INNER JOIN
           tstPatientDemographics tpd ON
           ttd.TestID = tpd.TestID INNER JOIN
           cfgLocations cl
           ON cld.LocationID = cl.LocationID
      WHERE ttd.TestStatus = 1 AND tpd.TestID > 0 AND
            cld.FeeCharged <> 0 AND
            (ttd.TestDateTime>={ts '2014-11-01 00:00:00'} AND
             ttd.TestDateTime<{ts '2014-12-01 00:00:00'}) 
     )
SELECT t.*
FROM ((select id, lastname, firtstname, location, testdatetime, readerlastname, readerfirstname,
              sum(feecharged) as feecharged
       from cte
       group by id, lastname, firtstname, location, testdatetime, readerlastname, readerfirstname
      ) union all
      (select NULL, NULL, NULL, location, NULL, NULL, NULL,
              sum(feecharged) as feecharged
       from cte
       group by location
      )
     ) t
ORDER BY location, (case when id is null then 2 else 1 end);
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon.  My DB is returning "Incorrect syntax near 'SETS'".  I am wondering if my DB doesn't support Grouping Sets.

Comment: I have verified that my database is SQL Server 2005, and so I can't do the Grouping Sets, so this doesn't work, though it gets me more than I had.

Comment: This is great.  Thanks, Gordon.